# saving as PDF file on VBA return "Document not saved" error

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

the following code causes a "Document not saved" error:

```
sFileName = "C:\test.pdf"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wkbPDF.Worksheets.Select        
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type := xlTypePDF, Filename := gsPDF_DIR & sFileName, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties := True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas := False, OpenAfterPublish := False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

but it is sucessful doing it outside VBA (but it takes several minutes since the workbook contains more than 100 sheets).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Filename:` parameter isn't going to be valid if `gsPDF_DIR` has any value, because `sFileName` has already specified the drive, folder and filename.

Try using `Filename := sFileName`

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered the problem. The worst part is Microsoft VBA's error description. I was trying to save the file on C drive which has write access issue.So changed it to different location and it worked. Sometime VBA gives you error description which is unrelated to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that your output file does not exist yet. If, for example, the `gsPDF_DIR & sFileName` has been saved previously in the same directory, where your workbook is located, then this error might also occur. You can see off this issue by removing previously saved file under  `gsPDF_DIR & sFileName`  or simply move your workbook to the other directory.